char * vs unsigned char *
So I was playing around with char* and unsigned char* pointers. And I came across this issue:
Code:
#include <stdio.h>

void func(unsigned int max) {
  unsigned int* intptr = &max;
  
  printf("%u - %p\n", max, &max);
  printf("%u - %p\n\n", *intptr, intptr);
  
  printf("%u - %p\n", *((char*)intptr), ((char*)intptr));
  printf("%u - %p\n", *((signed char*)intptr), ((signed char*)intptr));
  printf("%u - %p\n", *((unsigned char*)intptr), ((unsigned char*)intptr));
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int max1 = 0b00000000000000000000000001111111;
  unsigned int max2 = 0b00000000000000000000000011111111;
  
  func(max1);
  printf("\n\n\n\n");
  func(max2);

  return 0;
}

Output:
127 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
127 - 0x7ffc9712c53c

127 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
127 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
127 - 0x7ffc9712c53c




255 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
255 - 0x7ffc9712c53c

4294967295 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
4294967295 - 0x7ffc9712c53c
255 - 0x7ffc9712c53c

So here Little Endian is being used, and clearly char is overflowing at 128. However why does it overflow and print out the UINT_MAX instead of -128?

It's implementation-defined (i.e. up to the compiler) if char is a signed or an unsigned type. Therefore you really have three separate character types: Plain char, unsigned char and signed char.

@Someprogrammerdude I tried it and signed char behaves the same as char in this case/compiler.

Also, when a type smaller than int is used in an expression it will undergo usual arithmetic conversion which for e.g. char will mean it's promoted to an int. That promotion will also happen when a small type is passed to a variable-argument function like printf. So the expression *((char*)intptr) is really the same as (int)(*((char*)intptr))

This integer promotion is also a reason that functions like getc or getchar returns an int. Otherwise its result could not be compared to the int value EOF.

@Someprogrammerdude okay, but even with that, wouldn't (int)(*((char*)intptr)) be resolved as follows: (int)(*((char*)(&128)))=(int)(*(&-128))=(int)(-128)=-128? Assuming &128 is just adress to some variable holding the value 128 doesn't matter what type of variable

Actually it's worse than you think... The format %u is for unsigned int values. You pass an int value, which is signed. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to undefined behavior. You need to use %d for signed integers.

@Someprogrammerdude yeah but in the code I'm using unsigned int max, so thats why I set it to %u. And I was first testing this out with UINT_MAX when I first saw this issue and thought that the char pointer started reading all the 4 bytes of the integer, but that wasn't the case.

But %d prints out -1 for some reason? Why is that?

C does sign extension. The unsigned 8-bit value 255 is the same as the signed 8-bit value -1. With all bits being set to 1. So the char value 0xff (which is the same as 0b11111111) will be converted to 0xffffffff (assuming 32-bit int). Which as a signed int is -1 (or 4294967295 as an unsigned int).

Strictly speaking, you should cast your pointers to type void * before passing them to printf for use with %p.  If you enable warnings, your compiler should warn about that.

Regarding the undefined behavior, that max or *intptr are unsigned int values doesn't matter, as you explicitly tell the compiler that it's a char (or unsigned char). When you do an explicit conversion (a cast) you tell the compiler that it should not interfere, and that you really know what you're doing. Which could lead to problems if you actually don't. Also, most compilers are able to emit warnings for mismatching printf (and scanf) formats and arguments. If your compiler doesn't do that then you need to enable more warnings. And treat them as errors.

There is no overflow here, at least as the C language defines it.
When you de-reference raw data using char* or signed char* pointers followed by * operator de-reference, that raw data is converted to the representation of the character type used. C has a special rule allowing any type to be inspected byte by byte using character types like this. However, it doesn't really specify the outcome.
The * operator says that if the result of indirection is invalid for the specified type, the behavior is undefined. But since a part of an int etc has no effective type in itself, we can't really say that the read byte has an effective type. And the only sensible thing the compiler can do then is to convert it to the type used for the access.
So you end up with the decimal representation of 0xFF expressed in 8 bit 2's complement signed form, that is -1.
Since printf is a variadic function, it implicitly promotes all arguments according to "the default argument promotion rules" turn small integer types like signed char into int. But as it does so, it respects the negative sign, so-called sign extension. So rather than type signed char -1 decimal (0xFF raw) you end up with type (int) -1 decimal (0xFFFFFFFF raw).
From there on you lie to printf with %u, telling it that the passed argument -1 of type int is actually unsigned int. Strictly speaking undefined behavior but in practice printf likely reinterprets the raw data 0xFFFFFFFF into the unsigned equivalent, 4294967295.
